# What exactly happened between Georg Meier and Elisabeth Paehtz / the German chess federation?

Tags: history

Today in chess news is [German GM Georg Meier transferring to the Uruguayan chess federation](https://en.chessbase.com/post/georg-meier-transfers-the-uruguayan-federation). Meier alleges a dispute with fellow German player Elisabeth Paehtz, and a lack of support from the German chess federation.

The article gives only this as the details for what happened:

> *Elisabeth Paehtz versus Georg Meier*
>
> The two German players clashed on social media, and during the German Online Chess Championship in May, on the ChessBase server. Continuous taunts by Meier had a massive impact on Paehtz’s psyche, which caused her to completely mess up her performance and not to play their direct encounter. Meier demanded her disqualification, later called the German Federation internally and finally gave an interview to the website Perlen vom Bodensee in which he flirted with turning away from the German Chess Federation and moving to Uruguay, his mother’s home country, if there was no reaction. While this went on, he published a private chat with Paehtz. Both have since sought legal help. At the time of our editorial deadline, a settlement of the conflict was not yet in sight.

I don't understand this description because if Meier were taunting Paehtz, then he can hardly expect support from the German federation. On the other hand, [another description](https://www.tellerreport.com/sports/2021-10-13-european-chess-champion-meier--i-d-rather-go-to-uruguay.r1Se5Z54St.html) of the incident is:

> From his point of view, it started with an insult that Elisabeth Pähtz tweeted. The German top player counters that Meier had previously teased not only against her, but also against others. Pähtz paid for the insult. She reciprocated by suing Meier for having published her insults from a private chat, and the Erfurt district court agreed with her. The dispute escalated further in an open letter that Meier initiated. The majority of national players demanded and achieved the dismissal of national coach Dorian Rogozenco, who is said to have preferred Pähtz. Even after that, the bullying by fellow players and officials continued against him, claims Meier.

If this is what happened, then it looks like a personal dispute between Meier and Paehtz, in which case what does Dorian Rogozenco have to do with anything? I don't get it.

I'm looking for the details about what actually happened.

**Edit**: Chessbase seems to have retracted the article, however it is still available through the [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20211027030532/https://en.chessbase.com/post/georg-meier-transfers-the-uruguayan-federation).

Comment: "it started with an insult that Elisabeth Pähtz tweeted."
Is that the one about being overtaken by women on https://perlenvombodensee.de/2020/05/08/jonas-super-samstag/ ?

Comment: @JohnTromp I have no idea, hopefully someone who does can write an answer.

Comment: @Allure: The German federation is in a terrible mess lately, one big botch-up following another. Personally, I don't know and don't even care (to put it in appropriate language) what happened, but worse, I fear the question is unsuited for CSE because of everything will be on a "He said, she said" base. The most reliable sources will be German chess illustrated mags like "SCHACH", but even them hardly will be unbiased. You will also find everything in gory detail, news at eleven, on blogs, tweets, boards et al. but don't be surprise if a writer's nose is a lightyear long ;-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I think a "he said, she said" answer is OK, in fact my ideal answer would be "he said this, she said this". I'm sure there are details in blogs and such but much of what I've seen is in German, and I would rather not rely on Google Translate for delicate issues like this.